# need to change background color with DAX measure - Not duplicate

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am new to Power BI just started my IT career. how do I solve this problem, its not a duplicate question.

**Note:** I have already got the required output using conditional formatting, but I have been asked to do the same by creating DAX measure for the report to the change the background color

This is my input data:

**Here are the predefined conditions I need in my DAX query.**

- If Type1 >=0, <=2 and then Yellow
- If Type1 >=3, <=5 and then Blue
- If Type1 >=5, <=20 and then Orange

**Lookup column is "Column 2"**

[image]

This is the expected output:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
Measure 2 = 

VAR q =
    SELECTEDVALUE('Table 1'[1/1/2021])

Return 

SWITCH(
 True(),
q<=2 "Yellow",
q>=3,q<=4 "Blue"
q>=5,Q<=20 "Orange" 
)
```

But its not working and I have also tried the same above logic using IF statement that did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your SWITCH statement to this:

```
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    q<=2, "Yellow",
    q>=3 && q<=4, "Blue",
    q>=5 && q<=20, "Orange"
)
```

It worked for me.